# Animating the Application Icon or Logo in the actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-animation

Is it possible to animate(rotate) the application icon in the actionbar. Not the menuItems but the application icon on the left side of the screen.

I have a circular logo for my app and I need to make it more dynamic by rotating it slowly and indefinitely as long as the app is running.

Thanks in Advance...
Happy Coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action bar accepts `Drawable` for an icon, hence you can use `AnimationDrawable` and define your animation frames in resources. Look through [Drawable Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) android docs to understand how to create and use `AnimationDrawable`.

Another way is to apply animation to an home icon image view.

Define animation in res/anim/icon_rotate.xml

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:duration="1000"/>
```

Access action bar icon image view from `onCreate` method of your activity and set an animation. Note: you may want to play with interpolator and repeat count for this animation.

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.icon_rotate);
findViewById(android.R.id.home).startAnimation(a);
```