# change menu icon to gif

Tags: android, android-actionbar

in my app there is a icon on the action bar, when i click something start to sync, so i want to change the icon to a gif and when the sync its over change it again

i tried this but the app crashes:

> ```
>  MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.update_data); 
>  ((Menu) menuItem).getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.space));
> ```

This is my code:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
    int id = item.getItemId(); 
    switch (id) {        
    case R.id.update_data:       

        Log.i("TAG", "on update data");     
        if(Globals.onFitnessTutorial){
            Globals.onFitnessTutorial = false;
            finish();
            CommonUtils.startIntent(this, ProgressActivity.class);              
        }           
        if (MyApplication.isBluetoothConnection) {              
            timerSync();                
            forLoadingProgress();               
            MyApplication.showLoadingProgress();                
            String str1 = getSharedPreferences("DateTime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("user_time", "");                
            String str2 = "2013-07-14";                             
            SQLiteDatabase sql2 = new SaveDataBase.SaveDateBaseHelp(this).getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor select = sql2.rawQuery("SELECT * from db_pedometer_info ORDER BY pedometer_year, pedometer_month, pedometer_day DESC LIMIT 1; ", null);
            if(select != null && select.getCount() == 1){
                select.moveToFirst();               
                String year = select.getString(select.getColumnIndex("pedometer_year"));
                String month = select.getString(select.getColumnIndex("pedometer_month"));
                String day = select.getString(select.getColumnIndex("pedometer_day"));                          
                str2 = year  + "-" + month + "-" +day ;                                               
            }
```

I want to change the icon when it's here:

> if (MyApplication.isBluetoothConnection)

**Update**

This way the app crashes:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
    int id = item.getItemId(); 
    switch (id) {        
    case R.id.update_data:  

        MenuItem img = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.update_data);
         ((View) img).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sync);
         AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) ((View) img).getBackground();

         frameAnimation.start();
```

Comment: Android doesn't support gifs, but if you have the frames of the animation you can use an AnimationDrawable.

Comment: on other activity i have a gif, i set it like this: webviewLoading.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/","<html><center><img src=\"loader_100x100.gif\"></html>","text/html","utf-8","");

Comment: how can i do the same thing with an image instead of a gif?

Comment: I think this link will be helpful. All you need to do is create an animation list with all  the frames of the animation and then execute it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: i already do that but, my app crashes

Comment: If you tried that and it crashes, it is better to paste some code and the stack trace so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I foud the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25377542/4838977)

only need to change this two lines to show correctly:

```
android:fromDegrees="360"
android:toDegrees="0"
```